# How to use enumMap in java

Tags: java, arrays, enums

How do you use enumMap in java? I want to use an enumMap to get constant named values that go from 0 to n where n is size. But I don't understand the description on the oracle site > [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

I tried to use one here

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.EnumMap;

public class Main{

    public static enum Value{
        VALUE_ONE, VALUE_TWO, SIZE
    }

    public static EnumMap<Value, Integer> x;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        x.put(Value.VALUE_ONE, 0);
        x.put(Value.VALUE_TWO, 1);
        x.put(Value.SIZE, 2);

        int[] myArray = new int[SIZE];

    }

}
```

This doesn't work. How are you supposed to use an enumMap?

is there also a way to do without `x.put(Value.VALUE_ONE, 0);` for every single element in the enum?

Comment: Define `This doesn't work`. You need not put SIZE as `x.size()` will give you the size.

Comment: `x.size()` is 3, but I want SIZE, which should equal 2

Comment: There are three elements including the SIZE element. If you remove SIZE element it will give the expected result 2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't attempt to store the size in the enumeration, `EnumMap` has a `size` method for that.

```
public static enum Value{
    VALUE_ONE, VALUE_TWO
}
```

Also, enumeration types have a static method `values` that you can use to get an array of the instances. You can use that to loop through and add them to the EnumMap

```
public static void main(String[] args){        
    for(int i = 0; i < Value.values().length ; i++) {
        x.put(Value.values()[i], i);
    }
    int[] myArray = new int[x.size()];
}
```

You also need to be sure to initialize the `EnumMap` otherwise you will have a `NullPointerException`:

```
public static EnumMap<Value, Integer> x = new EnumMap<>(Value.class);
```

If all you're trying to do is retrieve enumeration values by indices then you don't need an `EnumMap` at all. That's only useful if you are trying to assign arbitrary values.
You can get any enumeration by index using the `values` method:

```
Value.values()[INDEX]
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to initialize EnumMap in your code.

You could initialize it within main before x.put something like:

```
x = new EnumMap<Value, Integer>(Value.class);
```

And use your array like:

```
int[] myArray = new int[x.get(Value.SIZE)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static EnumMap<Value, Integer> x = new EnumMap<Value, Integer>(Value.class);
```