# Dynamic Named SQL Fields

Tags: java, mysql, node.js

So i've got a bot that serves as a roleplaying mamager handeling combat, skill points and the like, i'm trying to make my code a bit more general so i can have less pages since they all do the same thing they just have different initilizers but i ran into a snag i need to check if the user has a minimum in a particular stat Strength, perceptions, agility, etc

so i call

```
mainSPECIAL = rows[0].Strength;
```

Here's the rub, weathers it strength, percpetion, intelligence, luck, whatever i'm always going to be checking Rows[0].that attribute ie Rows[0].Luck for luck perks, and i already set earlier in my initilizers

```
var PERKSPECIALName = "Strength";
```

But i can't call

mainSPECIAL = rows[0].PERKSPECIALName but there should be a way to do that right? so that when it sees "rows[0].PERKSPECIALName" it looks up "PERKSPECIALName" and then fetches the value of rows[0].Strength

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use reflection:

```
Field f1 = rows[0].getClass().getField(PERKSPECIALName);

Integer attribute = (Integer) f1.get(rows[0]);
```

Where "Integer" is the type of the element your pulling from the object (the type of strength)

The field must be declared as public! I think there is a way to obtain them when they are not public but it requires more code.

Comment: doesn't seem to work i just get and error on Filed f1 "F1 is not a valid identifier"

`Field f1 = rows[0].getClass().getField(PERKSPECIALName);
mainSPECIAL = rows[0].f1;`

Comment: f1 is a Field instance and nothing else. You have to parse it to your type. I will add this to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a set of integers that you need to identify with a constant identifier. You might find an EnumMap useful. Have a look at [How to use enumMap in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357851/how-to-use-enummap-in-java).

Or if you want to only use a string to identify which perk you want to reference, just use a Map.

Java doesn't have reference-to-member like some other languages, so if you don't want to change your data structure, you are looking at using lambda functions or heavier language features to increase re-use, which seems like overkill for what you're trying to do.